# How does prolog differ in capability from a Java-based rules engine?

Tags: clojure, prolog, logic, rule-engine

I am new to logic programming. What kinds of problems can prolog and other logical programming languages (clojure.logic) solve that rules-based rules-engines written in, say, Java cannot?

What kinds of problems is logic programming particularly good at solving?